# unable to figure out algorithm in below problem

Tags: algorithm, max-flow

I have doubt in problem statement only, I don't want the implementaion. I will try to approach myself if you can give me an idea.

I am solving the [Doomsday](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/graphs/maximum-flow/practice-problems/algorithm/doomsday/) problem , I am not getting the this line:

> Government built `pi` pods in each city to carry people in case of any
>   calamity which will transport them to Earth and self-destruct.

I know the people are sitting in the pods but where are they going after sitting in the pods? Suppose there are 5 city (1,2,3,4,5) each city has some population, what should be the target city(vertex) as destination to save their life?

**Problem Description:**

> Today was just a regular day for everyone in Krypton until a news
>   flashed that a meteor is going to destroy Krypton in X minutes.
>
> Krypton has N cities connected together by bidirectional roads.ROAD
>   DESCRIPTION: It takes `t` minutes to travel from `i`th city  to some
>   city `j`th where `1<=i,j<=N`  given in the format `i j t`. Government
>   built  pods in each city to carry people in case of any calamity which
>   will transport them to Earth and self-destruct. Each city has `qi` 
>   population. As soon as the people hear this news they try to save
>   themselves by acquiring these pods either at their own city or in
>   other city before the meteor destroys everything. Note that a pod can
>   carry only one person.
>
> Give the minimum numbers of people who will die.Refer example for
>   clarification.

Problem link: [Doomsday](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/graphs/maximum-flow/practice-problems/algorithm/doomsday/)

Comment: Getting a free pod is the goal.  There is no "after"

Answer (score 1):

> I know the people are sitting in the pods but where are they going after sitting in the pods,suppose there are 5 city (1,2,3,4,5) each city has some population ,what should be the target city(vertex) as destination to save their life.

Once someone has boarded a pod, we consider this person saved.
So the objective of this problem is to maximize the number of persons who will be inside a pod before the asteroid crashes on the planet. Meaning, ultimately, that you have to find a 'clever' way to move the right amount of people between cities so you optimize the pods, since you can move people but not pods.